# How to reach and set a control's property outside of a Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, properties, controls

I am really new to programming and currently working on a C# Windows Forms application.

The problem is the following:
I have a Form with different objects and controls like: tabpages, textboxes, timers, etc .
I also have a UserControl form which I load into one of the main Form's tabpages.

I would like to write a code into the UserControl , how can I manipulate element properties of the main Form.

For example: when I click on a button on the UserControl form It sets the main Form's timer.Enabled control to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do this, but having the user control access and manipulate the form isn't the cleanest way - it would be better to have the user control raise an event and have the hosting form deal with the event. (e.g. on handling the button click, the form could enable/disable the timer, etc.)

That way you could use the user control in different ways for different forms if need be; and it makes it more obvious what is going on.

Update:
Within your user control, you can declare an event - In the button click, you raise the event:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler OnButtonClicked;


        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = OnButtonClicked;

            // if something is listening for this event, let let them know it has occurred
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new EventArgs());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Then within your form, add the user control.  You can then hook into the event:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            userControl11.OnButtonClicked += userControl11_OnButtonClicked;
        }

        void userControl11_OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("got here");
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for Your asnwer NDJ but could You please explain a bit more of your solution? And could you please tell me more about the disadvantages of my way because I would like to learn from my mistakes. Thank You!

Comment: The reason controls aren't public by default is to stop other artefacts from changing them - e.g. if any class could access your form's textboxes and change them it would be difficult to track bugs, etc. - it's much easier if only the form changes them.  Using events is a standard way of communicating in Form applications.  I've updated my answer with a more concrete sample.

Comment: No matter how hard I try I just can't get this to work, does It work for You? I tried copying your exact code but It shows an error at: UserControl1.OnButtonClicked += new .... that An object reference is required for the non-static field, method... so I created a new instance but It does nothing.
I am getting really confused about this. I think I am missing the logic in this. Why cant I just say: hey Listen I am Usercontrol1 and I want to manipulate Form1.Timer1.Enabled property to the value= true? This would sound a logic move to me.

Comment: yes it works for me - I dragged a user control onto the form and used the code above (the user control just had one button with the event). Do you have a user control on the form already?  
I get what you're saying - it seems complex, but it's the right way to do it.  The only other real option is to make the controls (such as timer) internal and pass an instance of Form1 to the user control (e.g. a custom method or the constructor), which can be stored locally and then manipulated as needs be.

Comment: I've updated the example with a simpler version - literally I created a new Windows app, added a new user control, put one button on it and double clicked the button to create the button1_click event.  I then built the solution so the user control would show on the toolbox, dragged one onto Form1 and put the rest of the code.  Hope this helps.  If you have issues it might be worth updating your question with some of your code.

Comment: Ohhh I am such an idiot! :D Thank You for mentioning that I should add the usercontrol to the form. In the code I added so many user controls I just so overlooked adding this one. Well that really helped and solved my problem. I am really thankfull to You for taking your time and helping me Thank You so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `timer1.Modifiers` property to "internal" and access it with an instance to `Form1`:

```
form1.timer1.Enabled = true;
```

You need to have an instance of your class `Form1`, not the class itself. For example:

```
// INVALID
Form1.timer1.Enabled = true;

// VALID
var form1 = Form1.ActiveForm;
form1.timer1.Enabled = true;
```

But this is not a very clean way to do this, you would rather use events as described in NDJ's answer.

Comment: Thank You csharpler for Your answer but I tried to do this and I got an error message saying: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property '...'
Do you know why I got this error?

Comment: Thank You for taking Your time! It still shows me an error code: ...does not contain a definition for 'timer1' and no extension method 'timer1' accepting a first argument of type ...
but I think I will stick to NDJ's answer and try to figure it out. But Thank You for Your answer as well!

Comment: @szabolcsmolnar You have to replace `timer1` with whatever your timer (or the control you are trying to access) is called (according to your question, I see it is called `Timer1` (capitalized), so `form1.Timer1.Enabled = true` should work.

Comment: No, no I wrote timer1 because It was in your example but in my I used the correct timer name but It didn't work. I made an instance of it with: Form1 form1 = new Form1(); and it worked but It is not a possible solution because I have to manipulate the form which already opened and not another instance of it.

Comment: @szabolcsmolnar you are creating another instance of `Form1`. Instead, as I suggested, you could use `Form1.ActiveForm` or pass a reference to the currently opened window to the `UserControl`'s constructor.

Comment: I know but if a leave it as Form1.ActiveForm is just shows that error I previously mentioned. Does it work for You?

Comment: I have successfully used this way several times before. please show the way you implemented the code to help you find your mistake

Answer (score 1):

You may want to rethink what it is you are trying to accomplish. However, to answer your question, it can be done.

The best way to do it is to make a property in your UserControl called MainForm:

```
public Control MainForm {
    get;
    set;
}
```

Then, in your MainForm's Load event, set the property to itself:

```
userControl1.MainForm = this;
```

Finally, in your user control, set the MainForm's timer:

```
protected button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerName = "timer1";
    EnableTimer(timerName);
}

private void EnableTimer(timerName)
{
    var timer = MainForm.Controls.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Name.ToLower().Equals(timerName.ToLower());
    if (timer != null)
    {
         ((Timer)timer).Enabled = true;
    } else {
         // Timer was not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer icemanind but I get the same error as I got with csharpler's answer. As soon as I write the code into the main form I get an error message stating: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "Myprogram.UserControl1.MainForm.get".
Do you know why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. It's called events. On the user control you would expose an event with  a EventHandler for the form to subscribe to.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    /// You can name the event anything you want.
    public event EventHandler ButtonSelected;

    /// This bubbles the button selected event up to the form.
    private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (this.ButtonSelected != null)
         {
              // You could pass your own custom arguments back to the form here.
              this.ButtonSelected(this, e)
         }
    }
}
```

Now that we have the user control code we'll implement it in the form code. Probably in the constructor of the form you'll have some code like below.

```
MyUserControl ctrl = new MyUserControl();
ctrl.ButtonSelected += this.ButtonSelected_OnClick;
```

Finally in the form code you'll have a method that subscribed to the event like the below code that will set the Timer enabled to true.

```
private void ButtonSelected_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

And that's how you allow an event on a user control on a form set an object on the form.

Comment: Thank You it worked as well! I can't mark this as well but I really appreciate Your time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the below code,

```
(`userControl11.OnButtonClicked += userControl11_OnButtonClicked;`)
```

in a separate file in Visual Studio. The other file is called `'Form1.Designer.cs'`, and can be found in the `Solution Explorer` pane under

`Form1 >> Form1.cs >> Form1.Designer.cs`.

Hope this helps!